# What is the purpose of the XHR cross domain restrictions?

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

I was always wondering what the purpose of the XHR cross domain restrictions is.

It seems the intention is to prevent maliciously injected Javascript from sending private data to the attacker. However, sending data to any domain is easily possible with an injected `script` or `img` tag (or any other external resource for that matter).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If any arbitrary website could make an XHR call to your website, then the following could happen:

1. Innocent user Alice logs into your secure website and acquires a secure session cookie.
2. In another browser tab, Alice visits Bob's evil hacker website (which she thinks is just a Justin Bieber video)
3. Bob's page issues an XHR to your secure website. Without the cross-domain policy, the browser would issue the request to your website — including the secure session cookie — and retrieve the results. Those results could include anything available to Alice while she's logged in to your secure site.

As it is, even with the cross-domain policy, Bob's evil website can in fact POST an HTTP request to your server by posting a form. It won't be able to see the results, but if Bob is clever he may have discovered a URL in your site that allows some activity from a POST even if it's not from a form on one of your pages. That's called Cross-Site Request Forgery, and it's something the browser cannot protect you from.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better solution not to include cookies? This would avoid the need for hacks like JSONP. The only issue I could see is IP-based 'security' (for example in home routers).

Comment: Blocking session cookies on XHR requests would mean that the web page with a logged in user (auth token stored in session cookie) could not talk to the web server via XHR, because each XHR request would then be missing the auth token information normally tacked onto the request by the browser as a session cookie.  You can embed auth info in the XHR request without using cookies, but you have to write the code to embed it on the client and the code to extract it on the server.  And besides, cookies are only one facet of the cross-site access issue.  See my answer for more.

Answer (score 2):

Same-site security policy is designed so that for an attacker to be able to inject malicious script into a web page one of the following is required:

1. The web page references script or image resources that reside outside the web page's domain, and the attacker can gain control of one of those external resources.
2. The attacker has access to the host web server of the web page
3. Or the attacker has control of a machine on the route between the web server and the browser client (for unsecured http connections)

If you build your web site to only reference resources on your own domain, and you don't do anything stupid like accept javascript (or SQL) embedded in the URL or use javascript eval() on user input text, you're in relatively good shape for data privacy on your web page.

If you link to script or image resources that reside on a different domain, the security of your web site is dependent upon the security of that external domain as well.

The best way to protect against #3 above (man in the middle attack) is to secure all requests to your server (for page, script, and images) using https protocol instead of http. The man in the middle cannot produce a valid crypto certificate for the target domain, so the browser can at least warn the user that something is fishy about the site.

The classic case for same-site security is wrapping a target web page in an iframe on a page hosted by the attacker's evil.com server.  If the parent page URL and the iframe content URL are on the same domain, then they are allowed to talk to each other and see each other's internal data, variables, DOM, etc.  If the domains are different, the same-domain security policy states that the browser should not allow the iframe to see any variables or DOM info of its parent, nor the parent to see the variables or DOM of the iframe interior. This is to prevent unintended or inappropriate exchange of data between the two domains.

If the same-domain security policy were missing, then it would be a very simple matter for an attacker to wrap your bank web site in an iframe, lead you with misdirection (links on false email sent to you) to log in via the wrapped site, and casually observe all your bank activity.  From there, they can drain your accounts in a matter of seconds.

Note also that XHR was added to the browser environment as a third party extension initially, so the best course of action was to follow the existing browser security model for client requests.  XHR follows the same rules as the browser uses for fetching html pages, script, and images.  If XHR were designed into the HTML spec from the start instead of being tacked on later, things might have been different for XHR.  See the [HTML5 PostMessage spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/comms.html) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a web site for accesing some websites causing DoS. It's one of possible malicious using of cross XHR.

Comment: You can do the same by including hundreds of invisible images from the other website with random get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following wiki article it could help.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: The article lists ways to circumvent the restriction. These workarounds are what make me wonder the purpose of this single security measure. It seems like barricading one window of a house while the door and other windows are wide open.